# Host Migration with Differing Tables

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, data-migration

I'm going to be doing a hosting migration from an old provider.

- I'm moving a live site and a testing site over.
- They both have separate Magento 1.9.3 back-ends and separate databases.
- I've made changes to the testing site (added a plugin) which has changed the schema of the database, and added some configuration code.

I now want to move the sites and databases over to the new host and merge my changes on test into the live site.

What I want to know:

> Does Magento have some kind of migration tool that will allow me to preserve the up-to-date data in the live table, but apply the changes from test?
>
> Or would it be best to re-install the plugins on the new site and then overwrite the files with the modified versions?

I noticed when I was moving the test site over, and refreshed the site before restoring the database, Magento appeared to populate itself. Is this the case with plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Magento Data migration tool only migrates data from your Magento 1 site to your Magento 2 site. It will not migrate your extensions, customizations to code or themes. It will only migrate your data in your database.

By default, it will migrate all the data in your standard Magento install and you can extend the tool to include custom data. It will also migrate your setting and config but will not migrate admin users or ACL. (It will also not migrate your media)

You should start with DevDocs here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

You can log in with your Magento user and navigate to Training and Certification, the to Free Video Library. There are 10 videos from Magento explaining the steps in the process. There is one video that briefly describes the code migration tool.